# Forcing chef to update a hash attribute

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running a command that looks like this:

```
chef-solo -j my_runlist.json
```

My json file looks something like this:

```
{
  "my_attributes": {
    "list_of_things_to_Create":
    [
      {
        "source_file" : "C:\\myFile\\mypng.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  "run_list": ["recipe[my-local-cookbook::create]"]
}
```

The cookbook is already on my machine and I have verified that it works correctly in different runs.

I had to move the `.png` file, so I updated the `source_file` attribute to point to the new location for the png.

However when I run `chef-solo` again, the run fails as it keeps looking for the original location for my png even though I've changed it in my json file.

It looks to me like my hash attribute isn't actually updated at when chef runs, is there a way to ensure it does?

Answer (score 0):

As per the chef-solo behavior, it would take up the attribute value in json. As in your case, its not happening, it may be some small error in json or how you are working with that attribute in recipe.

Would you please share both jsons(first and changed) and the code where you are using that attribute in your recipe.